# Capturing Dynamic Link Clicks with SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an email with RSVP buttons that direct to Cloud Pages. I have followed the trailhead for the workaround (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/engagement-splits-in-journey-builder-using-ampscript/gather-your-tools) but the query isn't populating the new data extension I created.

Since the query uses JobId, does it have to be an actual send or will test sends populate? If not, is there something in my query syntax that I've missed?

This is the query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
c.SubscriberKey, 
c.EventDate as[ClickDate], 
c.linkname as [LinkName]
FROM [_Click] c with (nolock)
JOIN [_Job] j with (nolock)
ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailID in ('55151', '55164')
AND c.LinkName in ('CBC_2022_RSVP_Yes', 'CBC_2022_RSVP_No')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
c.SubscriberKey,
c.EventDate as[ClickDate],      //////add space here after as (space is not there )
c.linkname as [LinkName]
FROM [_Click] c with (nolock)
JOIN [_Job] j with (nolock)
ON j.JobID = c.JobID
WHERE j.EmailID in ('55151', '55164')
AND c.LinkName in ('CBC_2022_RSVP_Yes', 'CBC_2022_RSVP_No')

----------add space here after as space is not there "as[ClickDate]"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).